# Prove that is a norm in X

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a real or complex vector space, and let $\|.\|: X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function with
the following properties:

i. $\|x\|\geq0, \, \forall x\in X$.

ii. $\|x\|=0$ if only if $x=0$.

iii. $\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda|\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$).

iv. The set $B = \{x ∈ X:  \|x\|< 1\}$ is convex.

Prove that $\|.\|$ is a norm on $X$.

I can prove $\|.\|$ is a norm if B is a closed but it is too hard to prove with B is a open set.

Comment: Can you show what you have shown if B is closed?

Comment: Note that the convexity of $B$ means that if $x, y \in X$ with $\| x \|, \| y \| < 1$ then $\| \lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y \| < 1$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Now if $x \in X$, then $\| \frac{x}{2 \|x\|} \| < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y\in X$ and let $\epsilon > 0$.  Then $$\left\| \frac{x}{(1+\epsilon)\|x\|} \right\| = \frac1{1+\epsilon} < 1,\quad \left\| \frac{y}{(1+\epsilon)\|y\|} \right\| = \frac1{1+\epsilon} < 1$$ so that
$$ \frac{x}{(1+\epsilon)\|x\|},\ \frac{y}{(1+\epsilon)\|y\|} \in B.$$
Since $B$ is convex you can conclude that
$$\left\| \frac{\lambda x}{(1+\epsilon)\|x\|} + \frac{(1-\lambda) y}{(1+\epsilon)\|y\|} \right\| < 1$$ whenever $0 \le \lambda \le 1$.  Try the particular choice $$\lambda = \frac{\|x\|}{\|x\| + \|y\|}$$ to conclude that $$\left\| \frac{x+y}{(1+\epsilon)(\|x\| + \|y\|)} \right\| < 1$$ too. What happens as $\epsilon \to 0^+$?